# VS Code not recognizing that I have user name and email set for git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Having an issue that I have not been able to figure out.

I have git-bash installed from git-scm.com on Windows 10.

I have configured the user name and email globally. Using the command:

```
git config --global --add user.name me
git config --global --add user.email me@work.com
```

With a git bash window launched from the shortcut, I have no issue committing and pushing changes. the commits properly have the name and email.

From the git terminal window in VS Code, the same. works fine.

But if I use the **Source Control** view and try to commit changes in a repo,  VS Code pops up a dialog telling me I need to configure my user name and email.

At this point, I assume it's looking in a different place than what is going on at terminal (either in VS Code or stand alone).

Does anyone have a clue where VS Code **Source Control** gets its config info to operate git in that environment?  This may be related to the setting of HOME in the environment but not sure.

the result of running the asked for command is:

```
$ git config --show-origin --show-scope --get-all user.name
global  file:C:/Users/me/.gitconfig   me
```

Comment: what's the exact text of the message you're getting and does it have any action buttons on it? Please also check the Ouput Panel's "Git" channel to see if there is anything related in there to username or email.

Comment: Exact message is: Make sure you configure your "user.name" and "user.email" in git.

Comment: the output in the git channel is: Author Identity Unknown.

and it recommends running the config commands.

Comment: can you check if the last message in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148431 matches your setup?

Comment: source code for error message: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2d502be79d044ed34fcea16eeb02cf98b789789c/extensions/git/src/commands.ts#L3684. also likely related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/2d502be79d044ed34fcea16eeb02cf98b789789c/extensions/git/src/git.ts#L1566

Comment: what do you see if you run `git config --show-origin --show-scope --get-all user.name` and `git config --show-origin --show-scope --get-all user.email`?

Comment: so I noticed the UserProfile and home were not set to the same locations (one in windows format (userprofile) and one in linux path format /c/user/.....  I adjusted the home path to align with uer profile and made sure I had .gitconfig with the info present in the home path.   still no joy,  and still the get terminal sessions are happy in and out of vscode.   will look at the github path and see what help that might be.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: the commands in the terminal sessions return correct config info from the .gitconfig that is currently at my home/userprofile path.

Comment: did you restart your shells after changing your system environment variables? Because you need to. They don't dynamically pick up updates. Actually, I think what you are seeing is normal. USERPROFILE is a windows thing, and HOME is likely coming from GitBash: https://superuser.com/q/607105/1749748. You probably shouldn't touch those.

Comment: "_the commands in the terminal sessions return correct config info from the .gitconfig that is currently at my home/userprofile path._" - but you said you configured username and email globally. So why are you now saying they are in your "home/userprofile" path? What exactly is the path? to what file? Please edit your question to show the outputs of the commands I told you to run

Comment: I'll try and add that.  little challenging as there is limited ability for me to move info from where I am running all this (work) and my home pc.   I can't actually cut/paste in citrix as its disabled by policy.    To answer your question.   the file i referred to was the ".gitconfig" file (which is where the global options are saved and as reported by the command you asked for.  It reports global as the scope.  I was mentioning that path as that is the path to the .gitconfig file.   Also, I have been restarting the shells and the VS Code instance, fyi.

Comment: @starball Due to some environment vars VS Code was looking in the wrong place.   PowerShell terminal in VS Code shared the same environment.  I used git commands from there to set the global config name and email and VS code used them.   Checking the file system verified it created that file at a different location than git bash shell was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out mostly what was going on.  I tried using the git commands in the default powershell window and they also showed that the values were not set.  I set them using the commands there (vs doing it from my git bash  shell).   Those values were taken and used by VS Code.  checking the file system showed it created a config file in a directory that was slightly different from the one git bash was using for config files.

[more details]
In our environment we have HOMEDRIVE and HOMEDIR set to root path on a shared drive (windows). This share became R/O due to config changes I don't control. I also have no control of the setting of HOMEDRIVE and HOMEDIR environment vars.  I defined HOME to point to my local user directory with the form /c/Users/username to give git bash a R/W location to manage config. That was fine for git bash but but VSCode took it as path on c: drive.   Once I set the git config global settings from with powershell terminal in VS Code it set up a git config file in c:\c\Users\username and the VS Code git gui was able to function correctly

Comment: what directories was it using? and what directories was VS Code using?

Comment: In our environment we have HOMEDRIVE and HOMEDIR set to  root path on a shared drive (windows).  This share became R/O due to config changes I don't control.  I defined HOME to point to local dir under my c:\Users\username with the form /c/Users/username for git bash to have a R/W location to manage config. that was fine for git bash but but VSCode took it as path on c: drive.

Comment: I updated the answer with a bit more details too.